# Conflating queues

Tags: c#, queue

Are there any good examples of conflating queue in dotnet.  I have thousands of messages per second coming in from another system and i wanted to see if this was the best solution  and see some implementation examples

Comment: Will need far more details of your problem and proposed solution (conflating is too general) to be able to comment on "best solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the example you were after, but the best example is the UI message queue; mouse movement events can be conflated.

You could use [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(VS.85).aspx), and write custom code to perform the conflation.